# Starting up a collapsed dijit fieldset

Tags: dojo, fieldset

I'd like to create a dijit fieldset which starts up collapsed.

The documentation ( http://bill.dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dijit/Fieldset ) of dijit fieldset says there's only an argument called toggleable. But that's not what I want.

Is there realy no way to start it collapsed like

```
<div id="myFieldset" data-dojo-type="dijit/Fieldset" data-dojo-props="collapsed:true">
        <legend>myLegend</legend>
        <div id="aTextBox" name="aTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `open:false` parameter to collapse it at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the dojo fieldset value of open equal to false like so

```
<div id="myFieldset2" data-dojo-type="dijit/Fieldset" data-dojo-props="open:false">
    <legend>myLegend</legend>
    <div id="aTextBox2" name="aTextBox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"></div>
```

Here is an example of your code and the new version which uses the open property

http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/5rvwe1c0/